# Python open new files with same name of keys in dictionary in the json file

Tags: python, json

I want to create files with same name of the dictionary keys. For instance I have a json file like this

```
[{"Word": ["0"], "URL": "http://www..."},
 {"Word": ["10"], "URL": "http://www..."},
 {"Word": ["100"], "URL": "http://www..."},
 {"Word": ["1000"], "URL": "http://www..."},
 {"Word": ["11"], "URL": "http://www..."},]
```

and I want to open a file with key values name like "0" , "10", "100", "1000" and then I want to download the video in the values of dictionary which is in the "URL" section of dictionary.

I am trying to reach the json file with this code

```
import json

with open('filename.json') as f:

          data = json.load(f)
for words in data:
    
    x = words["Word"]
```

when I print x in that loop I get this ["0"]  but I want to get just 0 without  " or [] because I will use this value to create file with this method

```
     os.mkdir('Videos')
     os.makedirs('Videos/0')
```

or

```
for key_name in keys
    os.makedirs('Videos/"key_name "')
```

How can I read that json file and open new files with name of the Keys in Json file?

Thanks

Comment: `["0"]` is a usual Python list from which you can just retrieve the first item by index in the usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access the key of the `["Word"]` at position `0` to get the first item in the list.

```
import os
import json

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for words in data:
    x = words["Word"][0]
    new_dir = f'Videos/{x}'
    print(f'Create dir : {new_dir}')
    os.makedirs(new_dir)
```

Output:

```
Create dir : Videos/10
Create dir : Videos/100
Create dir : Videos/1000
Create dir : Videos/11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the first element of the list

```
x = words["Word"][0]
```